# How to do idempotent microbenchmarks or measure/emulate CPU cycle used by a program in isolation?

Tags: node.js, docker, profiling, benchmarking, microbenchmark

My goal is the following:

> Given program with fixed input and output, do a microbenchmark in an idempotent unit relative to the CPU work performed to compute the output. In other words, If you run the program multiple times with the same input, the benchmark should always result in the same value.

For instance, let's say I have this code:

```js
// Brute force: O(n^2) | O(1)
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) { // O(n^2)
    for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) { // O(n)
      if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
        return [i, j];
      }
    }
  }
  return [];
}

twoSum(Array(1e7).fill(2), 4);
```

I can easily do `time node benchmarks/two-sum-implementations/runner.js` and get time taken. But if I ran it multiple times, I get different times depending on what the OS was doing. Most frameworks will run it multiple times and then avg. the times, but I don't want that.

Some ideas come to the top of my mind, but not sure how to implement it, or if they work at all. So, maybe more experienced minds can shed some light here :)

- Can I use docker to run a program and track how many CPU time was used by the container that runs my program and exit? Would that be a consistent metric?
- Is there a program or tool that emulates CPU cycles so I can know much is a program using in isolation?
- How do cloud providers like GPC and AWS bill CPU by time? What tools did they use to measure that?
- Can you convert a program into its equivalent ASM (assembler) code and count the number of lines were executed by a program? Something similar to what the code coverage frameworks do with high-level code. They can count how many times a line was executed during a test.
- Based on the previous question, How deep can code coverage tools go? If it can go deep enough and it's consistent, I can microbenchmark based on lines of code executed.
- Any other ideas are welcome too!

Comment: Most OSes do CPU-time accounting per task.  e.g. under GNU/Linux, `perf stat node ...` will show task-clock as well as info from HW performance counters for core clock `cycles`.  Even `time` will show user+sys time = CPU time used, separate from wall-clock time.  But even that will vary depending on how much competition you had from other cores for memory bandwidth / cache footprint and so on.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the recommendation. I gave it a try and was surprised to see metrics for "instructions". Unfortunately, they also vary on multiples runs. I understand the CPU being shared with other processes but not sure why would the instruction change with the same program.

Comment: Depending on your kernel settings (like `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 0` sysctl), `instructions` might be counting user & kernel space, including interrupts that happen while your program is running, and of course kernel code in system calls may take different paths of execution depending on global state of memory allocators and whatever.  `perf stat --all-user` should eliminate most of the variability, leaving only stuff like retries due to spin-locks or `clock_gettime` retrying something with `rdtsc`, or IDK what other non-deterministic things.